# PhD vs EngD - Perception

Tags: phd, united-kingdom

I'm currently undertaking a part time BEng in Digital Embedded Systems Design and Development whilst working as a Control Systems Engineer. When I graduate I plan on doing an MEng in Space Systems Engineering.

After this, I want to move on to some sort of doctoral study. I have yet to decide whether or not I want to do an EngD or a PhD.

Whilst I understand that, on-paper at least, they are equally placed I'm wondering if the EngD option will be seen as less of an achievement due to the taught component and lesser research amount.

Is there any truth to this?

---

Note on duplication: This question is mainly surrounding the perception, both industrially and academically, of these two degrees.

Comment: @RichardErickson I know the difference between the two degrees, I'm mostly asking about perception. I don't believe that question addresses this aspect it's mostly on the technicalities of postniminals

Comment: Probably depends a lot on where you live.

Comment: @mathreadler the UK

Comment: Well, probably most of the people outside the UK do not even know what an EngD is (I'm one of them), so I'd say that probably a PhD is generally perceived more favourably.

Comment: There exist technical doctor degrees also outside the UK but they are less known than PhD. Many simply tell their students to say they are PhDs after graduation when technically speaking it may, or may not be closer to an EngD ( I actually don't know ).

Comment: I think the pragmatic answer is that for somebody who understands the difference, they don't care (or they may slightly favour the EngD in a few cases), and for people who don't understand the difference, just say you have "a doctorate". This isn't a consideration that should dominate over, well, just about any other factor, when deciding where to apply.